# Resize images to fit a div if no of images increases

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a div where i have a gallary of images and i am populating images dynamically ,now say if the no of images increases i want the images to decrease the size and fit in div

```
<div class="gallary">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg">
    <img src="img/img2.jpg">
    <img src="img/img3.jpg">
    <img src="img/img4.jpg">
</div>
```

is there anyway this can be achieved in client side using java script or jquery?

Comment: ...and how big is this div, are you floating the images, are the images all the same size/shape, etc? (Need more input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you're going to have to incorporate a scaling function into your javascript and I would also use php.

When the page loads, the number of images can be counted with php (if from a database) and stored as a form value or used directly as a global variable (both using php echo, else if no images to start you don't need to do this). Then when each image is added dynamically, you will need to add a counter function.

Assuming the images are all the same size and the gallery div is a square, add a class name that is unique to the images only (say "imageClass"), then update sizes with jquery.

```
//I'm assuming gallery is a square of height 800px and width 800px...change as necessary...this function would produced square images...if rectangular images are desired, you would need to scale images by the length : width ratio

functon resizeImages() {
    var counter = document.forms.MyForm.imageCount.value;//or 0 if no images to start
    var newImageWidth = 800 / counter;
    var newImageHeight = 800 / counter;
    $(".imageClass").css("width", newImageWidth);
    $(".imageClass").css("height", newImageHeight);
}
```

Comment: thanks works great but if the no of images increase say 1000 then the image will not be visible what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can write a javascript. follow the three steps below.
1. You can run a loop to count the number of images.
2. Devide div width by number of images.
3. Set the result to each image width.

Comment: how do i achieve it ,a example would be great..